# Xcode 9, iOS 11 & WatchOS 4 Crashes Apple Watch App

Tags: apple-watch, ios11, xcode9

I have 2 Apps in the AppStore since iOS 10 and both apps have iPad, iMessage Stickers and Apple Watch apps. They have been working great up until the release of all the new Apple software, Xcode 9, iOS 11 & WatchOS 4.

The apps did not need anything changed for Swift 4 but my first error occurred when I try and submit my archived apps to the AppStore. I get error messages referencing missing app icons which isn’t the case. I found a workaround here on stack overflow by editing the archived files Plist and then submit to AppStore and this works but is inconvenient and obviously I shouldn’t have to do this.

My next problem is now when I go to use the apps on my Apple Watch they crash every time on startup.  I don’t have any crashes when it’s run on the simulator so I’m thinking the only thing I’ve modified since testing is the Plist of the archive.

Here is the link to the fix I was using to allow me to successfully upload my apps.

[AppStore Upload Temporary Fix](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg)

Comment: hi, did you found any reason for crash?

Comment: @HirenGujarati unfortunately not. I have made updates to the phone version of the app and was able to now upload to the AppStore without having to edit the .plist as mentioned above but still my watch version crashed on a real device even though it works on the simulator.

Comment: Same here, let me share more info. My watch app have 3 screens. It has global tint color blue. It also has complication. After few seconds by keeping watch app in background, and when open app, it crashes. There is no crash logs in iPhone device logs (Xcode Organizer). More importantly sometime that global tint remains inactive color (default tint color). And whenever it is default tint color, my complication also not updating. So seems there is some strange things happening;